# If I have two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ are of order $5$ which is prime, so either they are equal, or their intersection is trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ are of order $5$ which is prime, so either they are equal, or their intersection is trivial. Why is it true?

I'm not able to conclude why this statement is true. Is anyone is able to give a hint to understand this fact? or the theorem to conclude?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: every group of prime order is cyclic, and every non-identity element is a generator. What would this tell you if $H$ and $K$ shared a non-identity element?